# Using two different Sans Serif fonts eliminates bold font

Tags: fonts, libertine, sans-serif

Say I want to have my document in the default sans serif font, but I occasionally wish to have some other features in the document be in a different font. I am using `\usepackage{libertine}` to load this other font, and I get the libertine font to show up by using `\textsf{...}`.

However, now `\textbf{}` no longer works in the document to bold the default sans serif font. How can I work around this?

Edit: I found the issue. The problem was the following offending line of code:

```
\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmss}
```

I changed this to

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss}
```

in the MWE below, and all works fine.

MWE (solution found):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

%% Import packages
%% ================================================================================================
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}                      % Enable bibtex
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics,graphicx}  % Augment graphics functionality
%\usepackage{concrete}                  % Concrete roman font -- COOL MATH. This package has some conflicts with fancyhdr. Recommend not to use.
\usepackage{latexsym}                   % Symbolic fonts for LaTeX
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % AMS math formatting options
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   % AMS fonts
\usepackage{bm}                         % Bold math
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage[tiny,compact]{titlesec}     % Allow better control over sections, headers, etc.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                   % Allow better control over page layout
\usepackage[section]{placeins}  % Keep figures in section
\usepackage{float}                      % Define tables and floating elements
\usepackage{flafter}                    % Never put floats before their references
\usepackage{floatflt}                   % wrap text around floats
\usepackage{wrapfig}                    % wrap text around figures
\usepackage{subcaption}                     % subcaptions for subfigures. USE SUBFIG, NOT SUBFIGURE. SUBFIGURE IS DEPRECATED AND MAY CONFLICT WITH OTHER PACKAGES
\usepackage{longtable}                  % A multi-page tabular environment
\usepackage{threeparttable}             % tables with footnotes, capions all the same width
\usepackage{dcolumn}                    % decimal-aligned tabular math columns
\usepackage{multirow}                   % Allow table cells to span multiple rows
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % Formatting options for publication-quality tables
\usepackage{array}                      % Additional options for formatting columns in the array and tabular environments
\usepackage{caption}                    % Caption formatting -- use commands here instead of hangcaption
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}                     % Enable colors
\usepackage[table,hyperref]{xcolor}     % Better control over color
\usepackage{import}                     % Let latex import files from different directories
\usepackage{datetime}                   % Format dates and times
\usepackage{enumitem}                   % Better control over lists
\usepackage{nomencl}                    % nomenclature package
\usepackage{lscape}                     % Allow text to be written in landscape mode
\usepackage{lipsum}                     % Lorem Ipsum, for placeholder text.
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}

%\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}  %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif


\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=DarkBlue, citecolor=DarkBlue, urlcolor=DarkBlue, breaklinks=true]{hyperref}  % Allow for hyperlinks in documents. THIS MUST ALWAYS BE LAST
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss}



\newlength{\tempintextsep}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tempintextsep}{\intextsep}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}[6]{l}{2.4in}
{
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
$$
\left\{\;\;\;
\begin{minipage}{1.95in}
\centering
\fontsize{16pt}{19pt}\selectfont
\textsf{
This is a super awesome quote of super awesomeness.
}
\end{minipage}\;\;\;
\right\}
$$
}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\textbf{\lipsum[2]}
\setlength{\intextsep}{\tempintextsep}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As described, this sounds odd.  Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: @jon I've fixed the issue while paring down my code to generate the MWE :)

Comment: It often does!  BTW, I'd watch out for spurious spaces if you use `\textsf{ <text> }`; it should really be `\textsf{<text>}`.  (Perhaps you were just trying to draw attention to its use, however....)

Comment: @jon Indeed; this was just spurious extra space induced when I replaced the quote that will appear in my actual document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue at hand was that the document wasn't actually being written as sans serif, it was that the rm font was overridden with a sans serif font. This cause all sorts of funky behavior.

I changed `\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmss}` to `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss}` and everything seems to be working just fine now.

Comment: Now, try to do `Text \textrm{is not text}`, I can't test now but I suppose that they would come in different fonts. Wouldn't they?

Comment: The Community has owned your question. If you're happy with your own answer then you should select it. That way it will not continue to be seen as a question without an accepted answer.

Comment: @GeoffPointer I meant to do that, but forgot :)

Comment: The next thing is to find out how to get Community to give ownership back to you. That I don't know. You could hit the **contact us** link below. They'll know what to do.